# How to store a Value Object collection

Tags: domain-driven-design

Suppose I have a User entity. And this entity must have a Country field.

As a rule, Country is a Value Object.

And here it's kind of okay, and there's no problem.

But I got a ticket, which says that now on Frontend, Country must be filled in from the list of available Country (also I need to expand this list in the future)

This would be an easy task if Country was originally an entity, but I have it as a Value Object.

What to do in this case? Redefine Country as an entity, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when you maintain Countries as entities, you can store them as part of the User entity as a Value Object. The fundamental nature of a country object is such that its value is its identity, making it a good candidate for a Value object.

But IMHO, the list of Countries can be preserved as a static list because the list is finite.

I don't know what it means for your app to add a country to the list, but I am assuming that it is not as trivial as a CRUD op. If the list is rarely updated, you can maintain the list of available countries as a static list in code that is updated when necessary.

If the requirement is to often switch a country from available to not-available and vice-versa, you can store them as CRUD entities but use them as Value Objects in User.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still wanted to store this list not in code, but in a database. I am using C# and Entity Framework core(ORM). Did I understand your point about storing Value Object list correctly. (https://pastebin.com/TbQs7jRL)

Comment: That is, I will have a CountryList entity that will contain Counrties as a Value Object

Comment: Yes, you got it. Expanding on that, you store Countries in a table, treating them as entities, and list them in the dropdown. But instead of holding a Country identifier in a user record, you store the chosen Country as a Value Object. The Country VO in user is not connected to the Country table, which is ok because a country's data is itself its identifier.